# interference pattern when two sources are not coherent

Tags: interference

How would the interference pattern look if one source emits blue light and the other source emits red light in Young's double slit experiment?

Comment: You'll get an extremely rapidly changing interference patern that for all practical purposes washes out any trace of there being any interference pattern at all. You may want to investigate what happens when the freqencies are almost but not quite the same (say 1 Hz difference).

Comment: I'm confused. I thought the double slit experiment involved a single emitter.

Comment: @John, all that matters in the double slit experiment is that the light coming out of them is coherent. One can achieve this by means of splitting into 2 the light coming out from a single laser or having 2 very precise lasers which claim to be coherent with respect to each other. Notice that those 2 lasers should be of the same frequency too.